# Removing specific observations based on other observations within a group

Tags: stata

I am using a dataset from Brazil's municipal elections from 2000 to 2016:

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input str5 codmun_TSE str56 nome_candidato byte NUM_TURNO long votos
"58335" "WASHINGTON REIS DE OLIVEIRA"                              1 15702
"58335" "JOSE CLAUDIO DE SOUZA ALVES"                              1   487
"58335" "SAMUEL MAIA DOS SANTOS"                                   1    34
"58335" "SAMUEL MAIA DOS SANTOS"                                   1    75
"58335" "GUTEMBERG CARDOSO DOS SANTOS"                             1   430
"58335" "FLORINDA MOREIRA LOMBARDI"                                1   138
"58335" "SAMUEL MAIA DOS SANTOS"                                   1    29
"58335" "JOSE CLAUDIO DE SOUZA ALVES"                              1   838
"58335" "WASHINGTON REIS DE OLIVEIRA"                              1  9470
"58335" "JOSE CLAUDIO DE SOUZA ALVES"                              1   855
"58335" "JOSE CLAUDIO DE SOUZA ALVES"                              1   923
"58335" "JORGE MOREIRA THEODORO"                                   2 25328
"58335" "WASHINGTON REIS DE OLIVEIRA"                              2 25881
"58335" "JORGE MOREIRA THEODORO"                                   2 27187
"58335" "JORGE MOREIRA THEODORO"                                   2  9059
"58335" "JORGE MOREIRA THEODORO"                                   2 19770
"58335" "WASHINGTON REIS DE OLIVEIRA"                              2  9437
"58335" "JORGE MOREIRA THEODORO"                                   2 21744
"58335" "WASHINGTON REIS DE OLIVEIRA"                              2 14570
"58335" "JORGE MOREIRA THEODORO"                                   2 12535
"58335" "JORGE MOREIRA THEODORO"                                   2 30629
"58335" "WASHINGTON REIS DE OLIVEIRA"                              2 13435
"58335" "WASHINGTON REIS DE OLIVEIRA"                              2 37061
"58335" "WASHINGTON REIS DE OLIVEIRA"                              2 27949
"58335" "WASHINGTON REIS DE OLIVEIRA"                              2 30794
"58335" "WASHINGTON REIS DE OLIVEIRA"                              2 35184
"58335" "WASHINGTON REIS DE OLIVEIRA"                              2 11086
"58335" "JORGE MOREIRA THEODORO"                                   2 10240
"58335" "WASHINGTON REIS DE OLIVEIRA"                              2 12403
"58335" "JORGE MOREIRA THEODORO"                                   2 13461
"58335" "JORGE MOREIRA THEODORO"                                   2 14277
"58343" "MARCIONILIO BOTELHO MOREIRA"                              1  3155
"58343" "GEAN MARCOS PEREIRA DA SILVA"                             1  2999
"58351" "MARCO AURELIO SA PINTO SALGADO"                           1     0
"58351" "JOELMA ISABEL SANTANA ROMEIRO"                            1    81
"58351" "CASSIA APARECIDA DIAS REZENDE PEREIRA"                    1   445
"58351" "RICARDO DE LIMA BALTHAZAR"                                1   406
"58351" "JAULDO DE SOUZA BALTHAZAR FERREIRA"                       1  4874
"58360" "VALBER LUIZ MARCELO DE CARVALHO"                          1 11230
"58360" "EDSON ALVES DE MARINS"                                    1   221
"58360" "RODRIGO DA COSTA MEDEIROS"                                1  8264
"58378" "COSME JOSE SALLES"                                        1 18323
"58378" "ALZINIR SANTANA DE FREITAS"                               1  6300
"58378" "HELIL BARRETO CARDOZO"                                    1  3175
"58378" "SADINOEL OLIVEIRA GOMES SOUZA"                            1 31353
"58378" "SERGIO ALBERTO SOARES"                                    1  7127
"58378" "SADINOEL OLIVEIRA GOMES SOUZA"                            1 24964
"58378" "SERGIO ALBERTO SOARES"                                    1  7132
"58378" "ALZINIR SANTANA DE FREITAS"                               1  5060
"58378" "HELIL BARRETO CARDOZO"                                    1  2509
"58378" "COSME JOSE SALLES"                                        1  9754
"58386" "BRUNO ALVES BOARETTO"                                     1  4002
"58386" "WILDIMAR DE SOUZA FARIA"                                  1     0
"58386" "ANTONIO TEIXEIRA DE FREITAS JUNIOR"                       1   487
"58394" "OSVALDO FONSECA FILHO"                                    1   637
"58394" "SUELLEN DO NASCIMENTO DOCA DA CRUZ"                       1   334
"58394" "FABIANA FELIPE FARIAS DA SILVA"                           1   120
"58394" "RENATO LOPES DE OLIVEIRA"                                 1   459
"58394" "WESLEI GONCALVES PEREIRA"                                 1 26329
"58394" "ALEXANDRE VALLE CARDOSO"                                  1 13166
"58394" "CARLO BUSATTO JUNIOR"                                     1 27913
"58394" "EMERSON GOULART CABRAL"                                   1   504
"58408" "CLAUDIO AUGUSTO AGUALUSA DA COSTA"                        1   863
"58408" "ANDRE GRANADO NOGUEIRA DA GAMA"                           1  6772
"58408" "SHIRLEI DENISE NOGUEIRA RANGEL DE AZEREDO CUNHA COUTINHO" 1     0
"58408" "ALEXANDRE DE OLIVEIRA MARTINS"                            1  4738
"58408" "DELMIRES DE OLIVEIRA BRAGA"                               1  4172
"58408" "FELIPE DO NASCIMENTO LOPES"                               1  3675
"58416" "PAULO ROBERTO ALVES RODRIGUES"                            1  5235
"58416" "MANOEL QUEIROZ FARIA"                                     1  6411
"58416" "GELSIMAR GONZAGA"                                         1     0
"58424" "OSCAR JOSE DE SOUSA"                                      1     0
"58424" "MIGUEL ANGELO STEFFAN DE SOUZA"                           1  2435
"58424" "FAUSTO FONTANET TEIXEIRA"                                 1     0
"58424" "ANABAL BARBOSA DE SOUZA"                                  1 24124
"58424" "FABIO FRANCISCO DA SILVA"                                 1  4416
"58424" "ANTONIO HELENO DE AZEVEDO"                                1   868
"58424" "LUCIANO HENRIQUE PEREIRA"                                 1     0
"58432" "THIEGO LADEIRA DA SILVEIRA"                               1  1325
"58432" "MARCUS VINICIUS DE OLIVEIRA PINTO"                        1 37333
"58432" "ALEXANDRE PEREIRA DA SILVA"                               1 14738
"58432" "LUIZ FERNANDO NOGUEIRA DA GAMA GOUVEIA"                   1  2336
"58440" "EDUARDO GUEDES DA SILVA"                                  1  8383
"58440" "EDUARDO SANCLER JACOB DO AMARAL"                          1  5533
"58440" "ADRIANO JOSE DOS SANTOS"                                  1   256
"58440" "LUIZ HENRIQUE LEMOS"                                      1    83
"58440" "DENILSON SAMPAIO DA SILVA"                                1  5123
"58459" "JOSE ELIEZER TOSTES PINTO"                                1  2983
"58459" "JOSE BERNARDO DE OLIVEIRA"                                1    74
"58459" "RIVELINO DA SILVA BUENO"                                  1  3091
"58459" "LEONARDO BASTOS MENDES"                                   1    44
"58467" "JORGE LUCIO FERREIRA MIRANDA"                             1 26861
"58467" "ARTUR MESSIAS DA SILVEIRA"                                1  3046
"58467" "ROGELSON SANCHES FONTOURA"                                1 19805
"58467" "JORGE LUCIO FERREIRA MIRANDA"                             1 19461
"58467" "ROGELSON SANCHES FONTOURA"                                1 21060
"58467" "ARTUR MESSIAS DA SILVEIRA"                                1  2582
"58475" "ALUIZIO DOS SANTOS JUNIOR"                                1 28603
"58475" "DANILO FUNKE LEME"                                        1  2853
"58475" "PEDRO VILASBOAS SOUZA"                                    1   129
"58475" "IGOR PAES NUNES SARDINHA"                                 1  4644
"58475" "IGOR PAES NUNES SARDINHA"                                 1  5408
"58475" "LEONARDO ESTEVES DA SILVA"                                1     0
"58475" "FRANCISCO ALVES MACHADO NETO"                             1 13093
"58475" "LEONARDO ESTEVES DA SILVA"                                1     0
"58475" "DANILO FUNKE LEME"                                        1  4054
"58475" "PEDRO VILASBOAS SOUZA"                                    1   175
"58475" "ALUIZIO DOS SANTOS JUNIOR"                                1 34794
"58475" "FRANCISCO ALVES MACHADO NETO"                             1 14100
"58491" "RAFAEL SANTOS DE SOUZA"                                   1 41758
"58491" "SONIA DE OLIVEIRA STHOFFEL"                               1   925
"58491" "PAULO AFONSO ABREU DE OLIVEIRA"                           1   406
"58491" "RAFAEL SANTOS DE SOUZA"                                   1 39843
"58491" "PAULO AFONSO ABREU DE OLIVEIRA"                           1   360
"58491" "RENATO COZZOLINO HARB"                                    1 18700
"58491" "SONIA DE OLIVEIRA STHOFFEL"                               1  1655
"58491" "DANIEL KLEIN"                                             1   604
"58491" "RENATO COZZOLINO HARB"                                    1 22743
"58491" "DANIEL KLEIN"                                             1   559
"58513" "CASSIA MARIA VIEIRA SIMOES"                               1   320
"58513" "AARAO DE MOURA BRITO NETO"                                1 10111
"58513" "RUY TAVARES QUINTANILHA"                                  1  8430
"58513" "ALAN CAMPOS DA COSTA"                                     1  6952
"58513" "JOSE CARLOS DA COSTA"                                     1   399
"58513" "EMIL CROKIDAKIS CASTRO"                                   1   311
"58530" "CAROLINO GOMES DOS SANTOS"                                1   940
"58530" "MARCELO JANDRE DELAROLI"                                  1 33380
"58530" "BEATRICE MILLER CORDOEIRA"                                1   641
"58530" "FABIANO TAQUES HORTA"                                     1 39128
"58556" "REINALDO MEDEIROS MACEDO"                                 1  1027
"58556" "LUIZ HENRIQUE FERREIRA PASCHOAL"                          1  1043
"58556" "ROGERIO RIENTE"                                           1  4600
"58556" "ELCIO SOUZA FERREIRA"                                     1   994
"58556" "EDITH BRAGA COIMBRA MONTEBRUNHULI"                        1   476
"58556" "LUCIANO FORTUNATO SILVEIRA"                               1   229
"58556" "ARY KOERNI GOMES RIBEIRO"                                 1  3505
"58572" "CARLOS FREDERICO CASTELO BRANCO"                          1   113
"58572" "MAURICIO RUIZ CASTELO BRANCO"                             1  1700
"58572" "TALLES TAVARES BARREIROS"                                 1  2580
"58572" "ANDRE PINTO DE AFONSECA"                                  1  7465
"58572" "ROBERTO DANIEL CAMPOS DE ALMEIDA"                         1     0
"58599" "JUEDYR ORSAY SILVA"                                       1  3294
"58599" "IVANY SAMEL"                                              1  5415
"58599" "CLOVIS TOSTES DE BARROS"                                  1  7958
"58610" "SEVERIANO ANTONIO DOS SANTOS REZENDE"                     1  3517
"58610" "FRANCISCO JOSE MARTINS BOHRER"                            1  2757
"58610" "MURILLO ALVES RIBEIRO JUNIOR"                             1  3257
"58637" "FARID ABRAO DAVID"                                        1 15175
"58637" "ALESSANDRO ALVES CALAZANS"                                1  7258
"58637" "WENDERSON DIAS RIBEIRO"                                   1   262
"58637" "JOSUILSON SOARES DA SILVA"                                1   813
"58637" "FARID ABRAO DAVID"                                        1 14689
"58637" "WENDERSON DIAS RIBEIRO"                                   1   329
"58637" "ALESSANDRO ALVES CALAZANS"                                1  7647
"58637" "WENDERSON DIAS RIBEIRO"                                   1   669
"58637" "ALESSANDRO ALVES CALAZANS"                                1 10440
"58637" "JOSUILSON SOARES DA SILVA"                                1   831
"58637" "FARID ABRAO DAVID"                                        1 16610
"58637" "JOSUILSON SOARES DA SILVA"                                1   737
"58637" "FARID ABRAO DAVID"                                        1 14121
"58637" "WENDERSON DIAS RIBEIRO"                                   1   619
"58637" "ALESSANDRO ALVES CALAZANS"                                1 10029
"58637" "JOSUILSON SOARES DA SILVA"                                1   592
"58653" "RODRIGO NEVES BARRETO"                                    1  5875
"58653" "FELIPE DOS SANTOS PEIXOTO"                                1  4534
"58653" "RODRIGO NEVES BARRETO"                                    1  9798
"58653" "FLAVIO ALVES SERAFINI"                                    1  7973
"58653" "FELIPE DOS SANTOS PEIXOTO"                                1 11828
"58653" "FELIPE DOS SANTOS PEIXOTO"                                1  5628
"58653" "FELIPE DOS SANTOS PEIXOTO"                                1  5406
"58653" "DANIELLE BORNIA DE CASTRO"                                1   110
"58653" "FLAVIO ALVES SERAFINI"                                    1  5144
"58653" "FELIPE DOS SANTOS PEIXOTO"                                1  9543
"58653" "FELIPE DOS SANTOS PEIXOTO"                                1  5271
"58653" "RODRIGO NEVES BARRETO"                                    1 17690
"58653" "FLAVIO ALVES SERAFINI"                                    1  3524
"58653" "DANIELLE BORNIA DE CASTRO"                                1   233
"58653" "DANIELLE BORNIA DE CASTRO"                                1   187
"58653" "FLAVIO ALVES SERAFINI"                                    1  4608
"58653" "RODRIGO NEVES BARRETO"                                    1  9912
"58653" "RODRIGO NEVES BARRETO"                                    1 20792
"58653" "FLAVIO ALVES SERAFINI"                                    1  3233
"58653" "RODRIGO NEVES BARRETO"                                    1 10989
"58653" "RODRIGO NEVES BARRETO"                                    1  9676
"58653" "DANIELLE BORNIA DE CASTRO"                                1   152
"58653" "DANIELLE BORNIA DE CASTRO"                                1    92
"58653" "DANIELLE BORNIA DE CASTRO"                                1   167
"58653" "DANIELLE BORNIA DE CASTRO"                                1   124
"58653" "DANIELLE BORNIA DE CASTRO"                                1   173
"58653" "FLAVIO ALVES SERAFINI"                                    1  2776
"58653" "FELIPE DOS SANTOS PEIXOTO"                                1  7253
"58653" "FELIPE DOS SANTOS PEIXOTO"                                1  4878
"58653" "FLAVIO ALVES SERAFINI"                                    1  3535
"58653" "FELIPE DOS SANTOS PEIXOTO"                                1  5160
"58653" "RODRIGO NEVES BARRETO"                                    1  7422
"58653" "RODRIGO NEVES BARRETO"                                    1  4442
"58653" "DANIELLE BORNIA DE CASTRO"                                1   181
"58653" "RODRIGO NEVES BARRETO"                                    1 12935
"58653" "FLAVIO ALVES SERAFINI"                                    1  8927
"58653" "FLAVIO ALVES SERAFINI"                                    1  2685
"58653" "FELIPE DOS SANTOS PEIXOTO"                                1 10564
"58653" "FLAVIO ALVES SERAFINI"                                    1  4664
"58653" "DANIELLE BORNIA DE CASTRO"                                1   193
"58653" "FELIPE DOS SANTOS PEIXOTO"                                2  6472
"58653" "FELIPE DOS SANTOS PEIXOTO"                                2 15537
"58653" "RODRIGO NEVES BARRETO"                                    2 12372
end
```

Where:

- `codmun_TSE` is each city's individual ID number
- `nome_candidato` is the name of the mayor candidate
- `NUM_TURNO` is the number of the specific round of the observation, so that if it's the first round it's 1, and if it's the second round it's 2 (maximum of 2 rounds)
- `votos` is the number of votes in the voting zone.

The names are being repeated because there are multiple voting zones per city.

In Brazil, there are three possible scenarios in a mayor election:

- If a city has less than 250000 inhabitants, the candidate with most votes win (no second round can happen).
- If a city has more than 250000 inhabitants then there can be a second round or not (the specifics are irrelevant to the question i'm posing).

As you can see in the example above, there are cities that only have first rounds and some that have first and second rounds. I don't have the population of each city available on my dataset.

I want to get rid of the first round observations when there's a second round.

Specifically:

When a `codmun_TSE` (city) has a second round, I want to eliminate all of the first round observations within that specific `codmun_TSE`.

This means that, for the example listed above, I would like to delete all the observations matching `NUM_TURNO = 1` **and** `codmun_TSE = 58335`, since we can already see that at some point there is a second round in that city.

I have been trying to do some loops for specific observations, but to no avail. I have also tried using `bysort` but I can't seem to find out how to do what I want.

Comment: Please use `dataex` to provide us with a sample of your data.

Comment: Hey, I just did that, thanks!

Comment: Hey, friend, check my comment below!! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
generate tag1 = _n
bysort codmun_TSE NUM_TURNO: generate tag2 = _n

bysort codmun_TSE NUM_TURNO : replace nome_candidato = "" if NUM_TURNO < 2 & tag1 == tag2
bysort codmun_TSE NUM_TURNO : replace codmun_TSE = "" if NUM_TURNO < 2 & tag1 == tag2

replace NUM_TURNO = . if codmun_TSE == ""
replace votos = . if codmun_TSE == ""

list codmun_TSE nome_candidato NUM_TURNO votos

     +---------------------------------------------------------------------+
     | codmun~E                          nome_candidato   NUM_TU~O   votos |
     |---------------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |                                                           .       . |
  2. |                                                           .       . |
  3. |                                                           .       . |
  4. |                                                           .       . |
  5. |                                                           .       . |
     |---------------------------------------------------------------------|
  6. |                                                           .       . |
  7. |    58335             WASHINGTON REIS DE OLIVEIRA          2   13435 |
  8. |    58335             WASHINGTON REIS DE OLIVEIRA          2   30794 |
  9. |    58335             WASHINGTON REIS DE OLIVEIRA          2    9437 |
 10. |    58335             WASHINGTON REIS DE OLIVEIRA          2   35184 |
     |---------------------------------------------------------------------|
 11. |    58335                  JORGE MOREIRA THEODORO          2   10240 |
 12. |    58335                  JORGE MOREIRA THEODORO          2   21744 |
 13. |    58335                  JORGE MOREIRA THEODORO          2   30629 |
 14. |    58335                  JORGE MOREIRA THEODORO          2    9059 |
 15. |    58335             WASHINGTON REIS DE OLIVEIRA          2   25881 |
     |---------------------------------------------------------------------|
 16. |    58335             WASHINGTON REIS DE OLIVEIRA          2   37061 |
 17. |    58335             WASHINGTON REIS DE OLIVEIRA          2   27949 |
 18. |    58335                  JORGE MOREIRA THEODORO          2   12535 |
 19. |    58335                  JORGE MOREIRA THEODORO          2   13461 |
 20. |    58335             WASHINGTON REIS DE OLIVEIRA          2   12403 |
     |---------------------------------------------------------------------|
 21. |    58335             WASHINGTON REIS DE OLIVEIRA          2   14570 |
 22. |    58335                  JORGE MOREIRA THEODORO          2   27187 |
 23. |    58335                  JORGE MOREIRA THEODORO          2   14277 |
 24. |    58335                  JORGE MOREIRA THEODORO          2   19770 |
 25. |    58335             WASHINGTON REIS DE OLIVEIRA          2   11086 |
     |---------------------------------------------------------------------|
 26. |    58335                  JORGE MOREIRA THEODORO          2   25328 |
 27. |    58343             MARCIONILIO BOTELHO MOREIRA          1    3155 |
 28. |    58343            GEAN MARCOS PEREIRA DA SILVA          1    2999 |
 29. |    58351           JOELMA ISABEL SANTANA ROMEIRO          1      81 |
 30. |    58351          MARCO AURELIO SA PINTO SALGADO          1       0 |
     |---------------------------------------------------------------------|
 31. |    58351               RICARDO DE LIMA BALTHAZAR          1     406 |
 32. |    58351      JAULDO DE SOUZA BALTHAZAR FERREIRA          1    4874 |
 33. |    58351   CASSIA APARECIDA DIAS REZENDE PEREIRA          1     445 |
 34. |    58360                   EDSON ALVES DE MARINS          1     221 |
 35. |    58360         VALBER LUIZ MARCELO DE CARVALHO          1   11230 |
     |---------------------------------------------------------------------|
 36. |    58360               RODRIGO DA COSTA MEDEIROS          1    8264 |
     +---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Hey, man, first of all, many  thanks for the answer, however, this is quite the opposite of what I had in mind! Maybe I didn't express myself clearly, I want to drop the full observations (as in the complete row) that have NUM_TURNO = 1, within a specific group (in this case, the group is the codmun_TSE and in the example at hand, we're talking about the observations matching codmun_TSE = 58335) **if**, at some point, that city (codmun_TSE) reaches a second round, what I want to do is to be left with **only** the second round rows (for the cities that reach the second round)

Comment: Sorry, is this what you mean?

Comment: Hey, close but no.. because this eliminates the first round rows that I wanted, yes, but it eliminates **all** of the first round rows, even the ones pertaining to cities that didn't actually reach the second row, you see? I wish to eliminate **only** the first round rows within cities that reached the second round.

Comment: What about now?

Comment: Hey, it did work for the example I posted.. so thanks a lot for that, however, when I tried to extend it to my main dataset it didn't work, so I'm not sure what went wrong, the main dataset has more columns (variables) that I omitted because of space, could that be it?

Comment: What exactly did not work? You mean the rest of the variables (which you omitted here) still have values? If that's the case you simply also need to `replace` their values to `.` using the condition specified above.

Comment: Of course, I was just about to check mark it, it was very helpful! If you could be so kind as to help me a little bit more..

When I use the commands you posted on the full dataset it doesn't work properly, it isn't just a matter of filling the "." in the other variables, e.g., Rio de Janeiro - a city that went to the second round in the elections - is left with all the first round rows untouched when it comes to the codsum_TSE and nome_candidatos variables, it just doesn't seem to work properly.. but again, thanks for helping me, I'll keep on trying

Comment: I am happy to but i do not understand what does not work, you need to provide further details

Comment: For strings you need to `replace` with `""` not `.`.

Comment: I just included a larger sample to explain the problem I'm having, I finally understood it.

Your commands work only if there are no more NUM_TURNO rows = 2 from then on, so since my dataset varies in that regard, it only works in the beginning and up until another second round election appears, because by then tag2 =/= tag1 and so it will not activate the command, I don't know if I made myself clear so let me know please.

Comment: the set is ordered first by codnum_TSE and then by NUM_TURNO, so that all the cities are ordered by code and within that order they're orderer from round 1 to round 2 (when there is a round 2). That way, your code works at first, keeps working when the first second round appears, but when another city that went to second round appears it stops working

Comment: Another comment, it actually **only** works if you begin with a city that goes to the second round, like the -dataex- that you copied and used, on the actual dataset, it takes a few cities until one has second round, so it actually doesn't work at all in this case, I'm not complaining, just correcting myself above!

Comment: Will have a look at it tomorrow.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, i forgot about it. Does the new version work in your dataset?

Answer (score 1):

This is an amended version of my code:

```
bysort codmun_TSE (NUM_TURNO): generate tag = NUM_TURNO < 2 & NUM_TURNO[_N] == 2

bysort codmun_TSE (NUM_TURNO) : replace nome_candidato = "" if tag == 1
bysort codmun_TSE (NUM_TURNO) : replace codmun_TSE = "" if tag == 1

replace NUM_TURNO = . if codmun_TSE == ""
replace votos = . if codmun_TSE == ""
```

Which appears to be working with your ***new*** example:

```
. list codmun_TSE nome_candidato NUM_TURNO votos

     +----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
     | codmun~E                                             nome_candidato   NUM_TU~O   votos |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |                                                                              .       . |
  2. |                                                                              .       . |
  3. |                                                                              .       . |
  4. |                                                                              .       . |
  5. |                                                                              .       . |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  6. |                                                                              .       . |
  7. |                                                                              .       . |
  8. |                                                                              .       . |
  9. |                                                                              .       . |
 10. |                                                                              .       . |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 11. |                                                                              .       . |
 12. |    58335                                     JORGE MOREIRA THEODORO          2   25328 |
 13. |    58335                                WASHINGTON REIS DE OLIVEIRA          2   25881 |
 14. |    58335                                     JORGE MOREIRA THEODORO          2   27187 |
 15. |    58335                                     JORGE MOREIRA THEODORO          2    9059 |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 16. |    58335                                     JORGE MOREIRA THEODORO          2   19770 |
 17. |    58335                                WASHINGTON REIS DE OLIVEIRA          2    9437 |
 18. |    58335                                     JORGE MOREIRA THEODORO          2   21744 |
 19. |    58335                                WASHINGTON REIS DE OLIVEIRA          2   14570 |
 20. |    58335                                     JORGE MOREIRA THEODORO          2   12535 |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 21. |    58335                                     JORGE MOREIRA THEODORO          2   30629 |
 22. |    58335                                WASHINGTON REIS DE OLIVEIRA          2   13435 |
 23. |    58335                                WASHINGTON REIS DE OLIVEIRA          2   37061 |
 24. |    58335                                WASHINGTON REIS DE OLIVEIRA          2   27949 |
 25. |    58335                                WASHINGTON REIS DE OLIVEIRA          2   30794 |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 26. |    58335                                WASHINGTON REIS DE OLIVEIRA          2   35184 |
 27. |    58335                                WASHINGTON REIS DE OLIVEIRA          2   11086 |
 28. |    58335                                     JORGE MOREIRA THEODORO          2   10240 |
 29. |    58335                                WASHINGTON REIS DE OLIVEIRA          2   12403 |
 30. |    58335                                     JORGE MOREIRA THEODORO          2   13461 |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 31. |    58335                                     JORGE MOREIRA THEODORO          2   14277 |
 32. |    58343                                MARCIONILIO BOTELHO MOREIRA          1    3155 |
 33. |    58343                               GEAN MARCOS PEREIRA DA SILVA          1    2999 |
 34. |    58351                             MARCO AURELIO SA PINTO SALGADO          1       0 |
 35. |    58351                              JOELMA ISABEL SANTANA ROMEIRO          1      81 |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 36. |    58351                      CASSIA APARECIDA DIAS REZENDE PEREIRA          1     445 |
 37. |    58351                                  RICARDO DE LIMA BALTHAZAR          1     406 |
 38. |    58351                         JAULDO DE SOUZA BALTHAZAR FERREIRA          1    4874 |
 39. |    58360                            VALBER LUIZ MARCELO DE CARVALHO          1   11230 |
 40. |    58360                                      EDSON ALVES DE MARINS          1     221 |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 41. |    58360                                  RODRIGO DA COSTA MEDEIROS          1    8264 |
 42. |    58378                                          COSME JOSE SALLES          1   18323 |
 43. |    58378                                 ALZINIR SANTANA DE FREITAS          1    6300 |
 44. |    58378                                      HELIL BARRETO CARDOZO          1    3175 |
 45. |    58378                              SADINOEL OLIVEIRA GOMES SOUZA          1   31353 |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 46. |    58378                                      SERGIO ALBERTO SOARES          1    7127 |
 47. |    58378                              SADINOEL OLIVEIRA GOMES SOUZA          1   24964 |
 48. |    58378                                      SERGIO ALBERTO SOARES          1    7132 |
 49. |    58378                                 ALZINIR SANTANA DE FREITAS          1    5060 |
 50. |    58378                                      HELIL BARRETO CARDOZO          1    2509 |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 51. |    58378                                          COSME JOSE SALLES          1    9754 |
 52. |    58386                                       BRUNO ALVES BOARETTO          1    4002 |
 53. |    58386                                    WILDIMAR DE SOUZA FARIA          1       0 |
 54. |    58386                         ANTONIO TEIXEIRA DE FREITAS JUNIOR          1     487 |
 55. |    58394                                      OSVALDO FONSECA FILHO          1     637 |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 56. |    58394                         SUELLEN DO NASCIMENTO DOCA DA CRUZ          1     334 |
 57. |    58394                             FABIANA FELIPE FARIAS DA SILVA          1     120 |
 58. |    58394                                   RENATO LOPES DE OLIVEIRA          1     459 |
 59. |    58394                                   WESLEI GONCALVES PEREIRA          1   26329 |
 60. |    58394                                    ALEXANDRE VALLE CARDOSO          1   13166 |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 61. |    58394                                       CARLO BUSATTO JUNIOR          1   27913 |
 62. |    58394                                     EMERSON GOULART CABRAL          1     504 |
 63. |    58408                          CLAUDIO AUGUSTO AGUALUSA DA COSTA          1     863 |
 64. |    58408                             ANDRE GRANADO NOGUEIRA DA GAMA          1    6772 |
 65. |    58408   SHIRLEI DENISE NOGUEIRA RANGEL DE AZEREDO CUNHA COUTINHO          1       0 |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 66. |    58408                              ALEXANDRE DE OLIVEIRA MARTINS          1    4738 |
 67. |    58408                                 DELMIRES DE OLIVEIRA BRAGA          1    4172 |
 68. |    58408                                 FELIPE DO NASCIMENTO LOPES          1    3675 |
 69. |    58416                              PAULO ROBERTO ALVES RODRIGUES          1    5235 |
 70. |    58416                                       MANOEL QUEIROZ FARIA          1    6411 |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 71. |    58416                                           GELSIMAR GONZAGA          1       0 |
 72. |    58424                                        OSCAR JOSE DE SOUSA          1       0 |
 73. |    58424                             MIGUEL ANGELO STEFFAN DE SOUZA          1    2435 |
 74. |    58424                                   FAUSTO FONTANET TEIXEIRA          1       0 |
 75. |    58424                                    ANABAL BARBOSA DE SOUZA          1   24124 |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 76. |    58424                                   FABIO FRANCISCO DA SILVA          1    4416 |
 77. |    58424                                  ANTONIO HELENO DE AZEVEDO          1     868 |
 78. |    58424                                   LUCIANO HENRIQUE PEREIRA          1       0 |
 79. |    58432                                 THIEGO LADEIRA DA SILVEIRA          1    1325 |
 80. |    58432                          MARCUS VINICIUS DE OLIVEIRA PINTO          1   37333 |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 81. |    58432                                 ALEXANDRE PEREIRA DA SILVA          1   14738 |
 82. |    58432                     LUIZ FERNANDO NOGUEIRA DA GAMA GOUVEIA          1    2336 |
 83. |    58440                                    EDUARDO GUEDES DA SILVA          1    8383 |
 84. |    58440                            EDUARDO SANCLER JACOB DO AMARAL          1    5533 |
 85. |    58440                                    ADRIANO JOSE DOS SANTOS          1     256 |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 86. |    58440                                        LUIZ HENRIQUE LEMOS          1      83 |
 87. |    58440                                  DENILSON SAMPAIO DA SILVA          1    5123 |
 88. |    58459                                  JOSE ELIEZER TOSTES PINTO          1    2983 |
 89. |    58459                                  JOSE BERNARDO DE OLIVEIRA          1      74 |
 90. |    58459                                    RIVELINO DA SILVA BUENO          1    3091 |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 91. |    58459                                     LEONARDO BASTOS MENDES          1      44 |
 92. |    58467                               JORGE LUCIO FERREIRA MIRANDA          1   26861 |
 93. |    58467                                  ARTUR MESSIAS DA SILVEIRA          1    3046 |
 94. |    58467                                  ROGELSON SANCHES FONTOURA          1   19805 |
 95. |    58467                               JORGE LUCIO FERREIRA MIRANDA          1   19461 |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 96. |    58467                                  ROGELSON SANCHES FONTOURA          1   21060 |
 97. |    58467                                  ARTUR MESSIAS DA SILVEIRA          1    2582 |
 98. |    58475                                  ALUIZIO DOS SANTOS JUNIOR          1   28603 |
 99. |    58475                                          DANILO FUNKE LEME          1    2853 |
100. |    58475                                      PEDRO VILASBOAS SOUZA          1     129 |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
101. |    58475                                   IGOR PAES NUNES SARDINHA          1    4644 |
102. |    58475                                   IGOR PAES NUNES SARDINHA          1    5408 |
103. |    58475                                  LEONARDO ESTEVES DA SILVA          1       0 |
104. |    58475                               FRANCISCO ALVES MACHADO NETO          1   13093 |
105. |    58475                                  LEONARDO ESTEVES DA SILVA          1       0 |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
106. |    58475                                          DANILO FUNKE LEME          1    4054 |
107. |    58475                                      PEDRO VILASBOAS SOUZA          1     175 |
108. |    58475                                  ALUIZIO DOS SANTOS JUNIOR          1   34794 |
109. |    58475                               FRANCISCO ALVES MACHADO NETO          1   14100 |
110. |    58491                                     RAFAEL SANTOS DE SOUZA          1   41758 |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
111. |    58491                                 SONIA DE OLIVEIRA STHOFFEL          1     925 |
112. |    58491                             PAULO AFONSO ABREU DE OLIVEIRA          1     406 |
113. |    58491                                     RAFAEL SANTOS DE SOUZA          1   39843 |
114. |    58491                             PAULO AFONSO ABREU DE OLIVEIRA          1     360 |
115. |    58491                                      RENATO COZZOLINO HARB          1   18700 |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
116. |    58491                                 SONIA DE OLIVEIRA STHOFFEL          1    1655 |
117. |    58491                                               DANIEL KLEIN          1     604 |
118. |    58491                                      RENATO COZZOLINO HARB          1   22743 |
119. |    58491                                               DANIEL KLEIN          1     559 |
120. |    58513                                 CASSIA MARIA VIEIRA SIMOES          1     320 |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
121. |    58513                                  AARAO DE MOURA BRITO NETO          1   10111 |
122. |    58513                                    RUY TAVARES QUINTANILHA          1    8430 |
123. |    58513                                       ALAN CAMPOS DA COSTA          1    6952 |
124. |    58513                                       JOSE CARLOS DA COSTA          1     399 |
125. |    58513                                     EMIL CROKIDAKIS CASTRO          1     311 |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
126. |    58530                                  CAROLINO GOMES DOS SANTOS          1     940 |
127. |    58530                                    MARCELO JANDRE DELAROLI          1   33380 |
128. |    58530                                  BEATRICE MILLER CORDOEIRA          1     641 |
129. |    58530                                       FABIANO TAQUES HORTA          1   39128 |
130. |    58556                                   REINALDO MEDEIROS MACEDO          1    1027 |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
131. |    58556                            LUIZ HENRIQUE FERREIRA PASCHOAL          1    1043 |
132. |    58556                                             ROGERIO RIENTE          1    4600 |
133. |    58556                                       ELCIO SOUZA FERREIRA          1     994 |
134. |    58556                          EDITH BRAGA COIMBRA MONTEBRUNHULI          1     476 |
135. |    58556                                 LUCIANO FORTUNATO SILVEIRA          1     229 |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
136. |    58556                                   ARY KOERNI GOMES RIBEIRO          1    3505 |
137. |    58572                            CARLOS FREDERICO CASTELO BRANCO          1     113 |
138. |    58572                               MAURICIO RUIZ CASTELO BRANCO          1    1700 |
139. |    58572                                   TALLES TAVARES BARREIROS          1    2580 |
140. |    58572                                    ANDRE PINTO DE AFONSECA          1    7465 |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
141. |    58572                           ROBERTO DANIEL CAMPOS DE ALMEIDA          1       0 |
142. |    58599                                         JUEDYR ORSAY SILVA          1    3294 |
143. |    58599                                                IVANY SAMEL          1    5415 |
144. |    58599                                    CLOVIS TOSTES DE BARROS          1    7958 |
145. |    58610                       SEVERIANO ANTONIO DOS SANTOS REZENDE          1    3517 |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
146. |    58610                              FRANCISCO JOSE MARTINS BOHRER          1    2757 |
147. |    58610                               MURILLO ALVES RIBEIRO JUNIOR          1    3257 |
148. |    58637                                          FARID ABRAO DAVID          1   15175 |
149. |    58637                                  ALESSANDRO ALVES CALAZANS          1    7258 |
150. |    58637                                     WENDERSON DIAS RIBEIRO          1     262 |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
151. |    58637                                  JOSUILSON SOARES DA SILVA          1     813 |
152. |    58637                                          FARID ABRAO DAVID          1   14689 |
153. |    58637                                     WENDERSON DIAS RIBEIRO          1     329 |
154. |    58637                                  ALESSANDRO ALVES CALAZANS          1    7647 |
155. |    58637                                     WENDERSON DIAS RIBEIRO          1     669 |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
156. |    58637                                  ALESSANDRO ALVES CALAZANS          1   10440 |
157. |    58637                                  JOSUILSON SOARES DA SILVA          1     831 |
158. |    58637                                          FARID ABRAO DAVID          1   16610 |
159. |    58637                                  JOSUILSON SOARES DA SILVA          1     737 |
160. |    58637                                          FARID ABRAO DAVID          1   14121 |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
161. |    58637                                     WENDERSON DIAS RIBEIRO          1     619 |
162. |    58637                                  ALESSANDRO ALVES CALAZANS          1   10029 |
163. |    58637                                  JOSUILSON SOARES DA SILVA          1     592 |
164. |                                                                              .       . |
165. |                                                                              .       . |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
166. |                                                                              .       . |
167. |                                                                              .       . |
168. |                                                                              .       . |
169. |                                                                              .       . |
170. |                                                                              .       . |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
171. |                                                                              .       . |
172. |                                                                              .       . |
173. |                                                                              .       . |
174. |                                                                              .       . |
175. |                                                                              .       . |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
176. |                                                                              .       . |
177. |                                                                              .       . |
178. |                                                                              .       . |
179. |                                                                              .       . |
180. |                                                                              .       . |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
181. |                                                                              .       . |
182. |                                                                              .       . |
183. |                                                                              .       . |
184. |                                                                              .       . |
185. |                                                                              .       . |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
186. |                                                                              .       . |
187. |                                                                              .       . |
188. |                                                                              .       . |
189. |                                                                              .       . |
190. |                                                                              .       . |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
191. |                                                                              .       . |
192. |                                                                              .       . |
193. |                                                                              .       . |
194. |                                                                              .       . |
195. |                                                                              .       . |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
196. |                                                                              .       . |
197. |                                                                              .       . |
198. |                                                                              .       . |
199. |                                                                              .       . |
200. |                                                                              .       . |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
201. |                                                                              .       . |
202. |                                                                              .       . |
203. |                                                                              .       . |
204. |    58653                                  FELIPE DOS SANTOS PEIXOTO          2    6472 |
205. |    58653                                  FELIPE DOS SANTOS PEIXOTO          2   15537 |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
206. |    58653                                      RODRIGO NEVES BARRETO          2   12372 |
     +----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```